# How to switch polling on and off in Apollo?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo-hooks

I use the `useQuery` Hook like this:

```js
function Foo() {
  const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(MY_QUERY, { pollInterval: 1000 });

  return (
    <>
      <Bar/>
      <Baz/>
      {data}
    </>
  );
}
```

Now, both `Bar` and `Baz` use the same query. `Baz` is a sidebar and I'd like to disable the polling while it is active.

I have a global reducer for handling the state of `Baz` and I modified it like this:

```
if (isSidebarOpen === false) {
  ...
  apolloClient.stop();
} else {
  // TODO
}
```

This stops the polling, but I don't know how to reactivate it when the sidebar gets closed (that is, in the `else` block above).

Am I doing this correctly? Is there a different way to toggle the polling of a GraphQL query with Apollo?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can start and stop polling dynamically with the `startPolling` and `stopPolling` functions that are returned by the useQuery hook. For more information, you can see the docs [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#usequery).

Comment: If polling does not work, check if you have set `ssr` to `true` on your Apollo client. Polling is not supported if server side rendering is enabled.

Answer (score 13):

This is an code example :

```
const { loading, error, data, startPolling, stopPolling } = useQuery(GET_DELIVERIES_QUERY)

 useEffect(() => {
     startPolling(5000)
   return () => {
    stopPolling()
   }
 }, [startPolling, stopPolling])
```

Comment: Thank you!  Apollo really should add in their documentation that if you add pollInterval to your useQuery, it will never stop!  Your code worked perfectly for only polling when that component is visible.

Comment: they have. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#polling. `Note that if you set pollInterval to 0, the query does not poll.`. the example doesn't illustrate `startPolling` and `stopPolling` though

Comment: How do we pass variables to the query?